# Ionic checkbox doesn't react on clicks

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I have a really simple view in my Ionic application:

```
<ion-view view-title="Search">
<ion-content>  
    <ul class="list">
      <li class="item item-checkbox">
         <label class="checkbox">
           <input type="checkbox">
         </label>
         Flux Capacitor
      </li>
   </ul>
</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Problems is, nothing happens when I push the checkbox?

EDIT: I found the problem, but I don't know why it doesn't work. When I add the following to my menu.html the checkbox stops working:

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-positive tabs-icon-only">

  <ion-tab title="Home" icon-on="ion-ios-filing" icon-off="ion-ios-filing-outline">
    <ion-nav-view name="home"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>


</ion-tabs>
```

Can someone explain why this is? 
Actually it is only the line:

```
<ion-nav-view name="home"></ion-nav-view>
```

That ruins it..

Comment: Is there any JS code that runs when you click on the checkbox?

Comment: nope, just the checkox

Comment: There is not enough code to help you. Do you get any console error? Put your controller code or create a fiddle with your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I personnaly set checkbox like that with ionic 1.0.0

```
<ion-checkbox ng-model="myModel.isChecked" ng-change="changeValue()">TEXT </ion-checkbox>
```